# How to open Tor browser with selenium using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec

Is there any way to open the Tor browser using Selenium in a spec.rb for an automated test?

When running automated tests, I see that the Firefox browser is open by default, but I would like to use Tor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Firefox browser with Ruby automation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435328/open-firefox-browser-with-ruby-automation-script)

Comment: @Nandan, não responte. Eu desejo abrir com o navegador Tor e não com o Firefox.

Comment: The same should work for Tor, just change the executable from Firefox to Tor executable

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180686/selenium-webdriver-change-firefox-path-to-tor/72876799#72876799